# FT232RL VCCIO Configuration

Tags: ftdi

I want to make a 3.3V I/O (UART) interface between a FT232RL and AVR which operate at 3.3V
For this configuration responsible it's VCCIO and must be connected to 3.3V supply. But what about VCC? Can it connected at 3.3V supply line with VCCIO together?
As the datasheet say for VCCIO

> +1.8V to +5.25V supply for the UART Interface and CBUS group pins (2, 3, 6,7,8,9,10 11, 21, 22, 30,31,32). In USB bus powered designs
>   connect this pin to 3V3OUT to drive out at +3.3V levels, or connect to
>   VCC to drive out at +5V CMOS level. This pin can also be supplied with
>   an external +1.8V to +2.8V supply in order to drive out at lower
>   levels. It should be noted that in this case this supply should
>   originate from the same source as the supply to VCC. This means that
>   in bus powered designs a regulator which is supplied by the +5V on the
>   USB bus should be used.

**This which i mean that it is necessary to connect 3V3OUT to VCCIO for get 3.3V level interface?
I mean: I don't want to use 3V3OUT for VCCIO supply, i want to supply VCCIO pin externaly with 3.3V line.**
And since i work the FTDI with internal oscillator VCC limited at 4V MINIMUM.
So, VCC must be connected at > 4V supply for normal operation. Am i true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 18 of the data sheet seems quite clear:

[image]

So yes, you need Vcc of at least 4V if you're going to use the internal oscillator.

Comment: Yes. so i am ok! and for 3.3V I/O interface (UART) it is necessary to connect 3V3OUT to VCCIO? Can i connect to VCCIO in my externaly 3.3V line? I connect the 3V3OUT with a capacitor 100n to GND

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/pdu2k4ml9/

Comment: Oops--sorry; misread your diagram. At least as far as VCCIO goes, it looks all right.

Comment: What will happening if in this circuit http://postimg.org/image/pdu2k4ml9/ the 3.3V line, wich supply the VCCIO, become 0V? Whats the level of UART output then? high impedance? 0V?

Comment: @GeoG392: The data sheet specifies a minimum of 1.8 volts for VCCIO. It's hard to guess what it will do if you don't meet that requirement. I suppose the data sheet *might* say somewhere, but I kind of doubt it.

Comment: i suppose that in the case of the line which supply the mcu (3.3V) and VCCIO become zero. maybe UART level its zero too. anyway there's no matter.